# Best way to set repository URL for Nix fetchpypi

Tags: pypi, nix

There is the nix fetcher [fetchpypi](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/build-support/fetchpypi/default.nix). The wiki has an [example](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Python) of how to use it:

```hs
my-python-packages = ps: with ps; [
  # ...
  (
    buildPythonPackage rec {
      pname = "deserialize";
      version = "1.8.3";
      src = fetchPypi {
        inherit pname version;
        sha256 = "sha256-0aozmQ4Eb5zL4rtNHSFjEynfObUkYlid1PgMDVmRkwY=";
      };
      doCheck = false;
      propagatedBuildInputs = [
        # Specify dependencies
        pkgs.python3Packages.numpy
      ];
    }
  )
];
```

What is the best way to use the fetcher with a private pypi repository?

I see that the [definition](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/build-support/fetchpypi/default.nix#L13-L15) of fetchpypi has `computeSourceUrl`. How could this be overridden to supply a different repository base URL?

Alternatively I see `computeSourceUrl` use [mirrors://](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/pkgs/build-support/fetchurl/mirrors.nix#L332-L338). Is it possible to override mirrors when calling `fetchpypi`?

Comment: If you don't fetch from `pypi`, then you probably don't want to use the specialized fetcher `fetchPypi`, but rather a general purpose fetcher like `fetchUrl`. You can always factor common parts into your own specialized fetcher.

Comment: It might be needed to adapt the url when fetching in pipy, I wanted to fetch the wheel version of google earth engine and they do not confirm to the scheme given in the computeWheelUrl due to a use of an underscore in the wheel name, so I'd like if someone would be able to help